# Pivot in oracle is not giving the expected result

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a table result like below

I have a table like the one below:

| PE_ID | Phone_Num | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 740 | NULL | test@test.com |
| 740 | 124567890 | NULL |

I am trying to get the result as below

| PE_ID | Phone_Num | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 740 | 124567890 | test@test.com |

I had tried with the below `PIVOT` query but it is not working correctly

```
with rws as (
  select 740 type, NULL Phone_Num, 'test@test.com' email from dual union all
  select 740 type, '711692162' Phone_Num, NULL email from dual 
), rns as (
  select row_number () over ( order by type ) rn,
         r.*
  from   rws r
)
  select * from rns
  pivot (
    min ( type ) Pe_ID, min ( Phone_Num ) Phone_Num, min ( email ) email
    for rn in (1)
```

);

It is giving the result as below

| PE_ID_1 | Phone_Num_1 | Email_1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 740 | NULL | test@test.com |

Please anyone point me to the right direction to the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want to group by type and find the minimum phone number and email and return only the minimum type. You do not need to `PIVOT` and can just aggregate and return the first row:

```
SELECT type,
       MIN( phone_num ) AS phone_num,
       MIN( email ) email
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY type
ORDER BY type
FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( type, phone_num, email ) AS
  select 740, NULL, 'test@test.com' from dual union all
  select 740, '711692162', NULL from dual
```

Outputs:

> | TYPE | PHONE_NUM | EMAIL |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 740 | 711692162 | test@test.com |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1e493ca5d6f124d2a7f3e75d445599f8)*

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to `PIVOT` at all. You can get the first phone number and email using the `FIRST_VALUE` analytic function.

```sql
WITH
    rws
    AS
        (SELECT 740 TYPE, NULL Phone_Num, 'test@test.com' email FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 740 TYPE, '711692162' Phone_Num, NULL email FROM DUAL)
SELECT DISTINCT
       TYPE,
       FIRST_VALUE (phone_num IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY TYPE)     AS phone_num,
       FIRST_VALUE (email IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY TYPE)         AS email
  FROM rws;

   TYPE    PHONE_NUM            EMAIL
_______ ____________ ________________
    740 711692162    test@test.com
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT peid, listagg(phone_num) phone_num , 
      listagg(email) email FROM table1 GROUP BY peid;
```